# <Response [502]> cannot be catched ？

Tags: python, python-requests

I am using the interface of a website to get data, and I have run multiple programs at the same time. I wrote exception capture in the program. I still get a response 502 error and the program is interrupted, and several programs will be interrupted at the same time. What is the reason?

```
def search(name):
    global n
    path = 'https://dev.***.com/api/company/queryByName?name=' + str(name)
    s = requests.session()
    s.keep_alive = False  # 关闭多余连接
    try:
        r = s.get(path,timeout=3)
        print(n,r)
    except (ReadTimeout,HTTPError,ConnectionError) as e:
        print(e)
        return search(name)
    else:
        n=n+1
        result = json.loads(r.text)
```

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "D:/PyCharm Community Edition/project/company/30.py", line 72, in <module>
    data1['social_credit_code'], data1['industry'], data1['reg_place'] = zip(*data1['companyName'].apply(search))
  File "C:\Users\13750\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python36\site-packages\pandas\core\series.py", line 3848, in apply
739 <Response [502]>
    mapped = lib.map_infer(values, f, convert=convert_dtype)
  File "pandas\_libs\lib.pyx", line 2329, in pandas._libs.lib.map_infer
  File "D:/PyCharm Community Edition/project/company/30.py", line 49, in search
    result = json.loads(r.text)
  File "C:\Users\13750\.conda\envs\py36\lib\json\__init__.py", line 354, in loads
    return _default_decoder.decode(s)
  File "C:\Users\13750\.conda\envs\py36\lib\json\decoder.py", line 339, in decode
    obj, end = self.raw_decode(s, idx=_w(s, 0).end())
  File "C:\Users\13750\.conda\envs\py36\lib\json\decoder.py", line 357, in raw_decode
    raise JSONDecodeError("Expecting value", s, err.value) from None
json.decoder.JSONDecodeError: Expecting value: line 1 column 1 (char 0)
```

Comment: Does https://requests.readthedocs.io/en/master/user/quickstart/#json-response-content help?

Comment: Read the stack trace `JSONDecodeError`. You don't get an exception when you get a bad response from the `requests` API. You need to check `r.ok` and only then can you do `json.loads(r.text)` if the response was successful

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `requests` API will only raise an exception if you are not able to communicate with a server. In this case you did reach a server, but the server then responded by telling you `502 Bad Gateway`. This error usually means you communicated with some proxy server which was unable to forward your message to the final destination.

Regardless, that response will be captured by the `requests` API and returned as a `Response` object. After you receive a response you always need to make sure that the return code is what you expect (commonly 200). `requests` has a convenient way to do so:

```
r = s.get(path,timeout=3)
if r.ok:
    # do your work
```

In this case you didnt check if the response code was okay, and because the response code indicated an error, you didn't receive any JSON data like you thought you did. Which is why the code followed through to the `else` statement and gave you a `JSONDecodeError`.

Comment: Thank you so much.You solved my doubts, I will try it.

Answer (score 0):

As the traceback clearly shows, a `JSONDecoderError` is being raised and your code is not catching it.

You should probably not attempt to decode the content of a `502` response.  If you want such responses to raise an exception use `raise_for_status`

```
try:
    r = s.get(path,timeout=3)
    r.raise_for_status()
    print(n,r)
except (ReadTimeout,HTTPError,ConnectionError) as e:
    ...
```

Comment: This is not helpful to OP. The question is why HTTP status code 502 ("Bad Gateway") *doesn't* cause an exception caught by `except (ReadTimeout,HTTPError,ConnectionError) as e:`, but instead allows the code to flow through to the attempt at JSON loading (which then has invalid data).

Comment: @karl I’ve modified to include how they might choose to have this raise an exception.